# How do I put an end date to a Twitter4J Query search result in Java?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

For a school project I'm trying to make a program using twitter4j that plots a graph displaying the usage of a certain word on twitter within a certain region between a start and end date, I do this by instantiating a Query object and setting the start and until dates to dates inputted by the user like this:

```
  Query q = new Query(word);
  q.setCount(100);
  q.setGeoCode(loc,100,Query.MILES);
  q.setSince(start + "-1-1");
  //q.setUntil(end + "-12-12"); NOT WORKING!!
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? As the query result returns no tweets (Statuses) when I uncomment the last line (setUntil) but it works fine when I don't include the setUntil()

Comment: That’s funny. What is the value of `end`, and its type? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: it's an integer same as start (although the actual value varies based on user input)

Comment: Weird. The way I read [the docs](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Query.html#setUntil-java.lang.String-), it ought to work. Again, a minimal reproducible example might help (not that I have any experience with Twitter4j nor have it installed).

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me. I hope this example clarifies your doubt.

```
 Query query = new Query(hashtag);
 query.setSince("yyyy-mm-dd");
 query.setUntil("yyyy-mm-dd");
 query.setCount(100);
           
 //Execute the search method in the twitter object. The results are contained in a QueryResult object that contains one object Status per Tweet
 QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
 out.println(result.getTweets().size());
 for (Status status : result.getTweets()) {
     out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" + status.getText());
     out.println();
 }
```